# What is the difference between Flutter for Web and for Mobile Apps?

Tags: flutter, mobile

I've been working designing mobile Flutter apps and I'm wondering if I could simply switch to front-end web development by using Flutter too. What are your insights? What would the differences be between web and mobile developing with Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web has very few plugins (generally have to be pure Dart).
Web has hot-restart, but not hot-reload.
Web doesn't have native file choosers, etc.
Web still has issues with nested ScrollBars.

Although it may sound even more restrictive, Desktop also has all these restrictions, **except** it can call hot-reload!  Yes.  You can also build a standalone .app or .exe to share with friends.  Hard to do that with Mobile.  Somewhat easy to do with Web, provided you launch it from the root of your webserver.